# Xpath selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a clickable button which links to www.snaptrude.com. But clicking on the button, it throws an error which goes like:

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a 
     variable
    - Syntax error on token "home", invalid 
     AssignmentOperator
```

Here's the  code I'm referencing to

```
package snaptrude;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Kunal\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String baseUrl = "http://www.snaptrude.com";


        // launch Chrome and direct it to the Base URL
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("snaptrude@snaptrude.com");

        WebElement f = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));

        WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="home"]/div/div/div/div/div/span[2]/h2/strong"));

        a.click();


    }

}
```

Comment: It's just a syntax error. Not clicking. You have unescaped quotes inside a string. Use apostrophe  `"//*[@id='home']/div/div/div/div/div/span[2]/h2/strong"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done syntax error :- please refer below code 
        WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='home']/div/div/div/div/div/span[2]/h2/strong")